# Cannot find namespace 'FirebaseFirestore' - Node.js, Express, Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm using the Firebase Admin SDK in my Express + Typescript server. I'm trying to use Firestore's method [withConverter()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#withConverter) However, I get the error "Cannot find namespace 'FirebaseFirestore'.ts(2503)". How can I deal with this?

```html
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

const firestore = admin.firestore();

interface BlogpostColletion {
    text: String,
    title: String,
}

interface UsersCollection {
    blogposts: BlogpostColletion
}

const converter = {
    toFirestore: (data: UsersCollection) => data,
    // PROBLEM HERE "Cannot find namespace 'FirebaseFirestore'.ts(2503)" 
    fromFirestore: (snap: FirebaseFirestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) =>
        snap.data() as UsersCollection
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `admin.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot` instead of `FirebaseFirestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot`?

Comment: Thank you. Changing to "admin.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot" gave the issue "cannot find namespace admin". But changing the import of admin from "var admin = require("firebase-admin")" to "import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'" seems to have solved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import `QueryDocumentSnapshot` from Admin SDK like this:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin"

fromFirestore: (snap: admin.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot)
```